# creating a button inside onclick listener?

Tags: android

I want to dynamically create a set of buttons when my program runs.I want these buttons to be created when i create a generate button.Is it possible to call `Button but=new Button(this);` inside OnClickListener of another Button?

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- just be sure to change `new Button(this)` to `new Button(mClass.this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. say `Button b = new Button(yourAct.this);..`

and do not forget to add it to your parent layout by saying `addView(b)`

Answer (score 0):

This does work.  I have an activity that creates a button in the same way.  To set onClickListener to a method in the outer class, you need to use (mClass.*clicklistener*) to set the listener methods.